How Does One Manage Deploying Static Data w/ DACPAC?
I am building a database for internal company use.  I have a SQL project in VS that contains all the structure.  This is in source control.  Now, there are tables in this database that will have static/controlled data.  Data that should exist, exactly the same, in every instance of the database, production or otherwise.  Currently, I am accomplishing this through a Post-Deployment script which runs a series of MERGE statements.  This script is also checked into source control.  My question is this: has anyone done it in a way they might consider better?  It feels a little weird checking "data" into source control, but then again, it can be seen as versioned.  In case it matters, we are using SQL Server 2019, on-prem.
Note: Please do not focus on the MERGE statements.  I am aware they are not everyone's favorite.  I have seen all the arguments against it.  But I have used them for this purpose for years, without incident.  My question revolves more around the process, the idea.
